# Unity 2018.3.0f2 Blank Errors

Tags: unity, editors

I am getting these blank errors in unity for quite a while now, as soon as I create a new Project 2D or 3D I am presented with the following and can't enter in play mode.

[image]

And as a workaround I have to change the `Scripting Runtime Version` to 3.5 in the project settings to make it work.

[image]

I cannot able to work with version `4.x`

I have the Window 7, .NET Framework 4.7.2 Installed, any help or advice is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably contact Unity (if you are using the latest version). I am not 100% sure, but I remember reading that Unity does not support .Net 4.x ... Again, you might want to report this to them

Comment: @GabrieleVierti But in Scripting runtime I have only two option 3.5 which is deprecated and 4.x which is giving those blank errors, but thank you for your feedback

Comment: Have the same problem, how to fix that 5 blank errors?

Comment: @VorTrexOfficial If you are running windows 7 then change the sripting runtime version to 3.5 will solve the problem temporarily, however the ultimate fix for me is to upgrade to windows 10.